# Find a point on a circle which contains a rectangle using another point, the angle between the two and the rectangle's dimensions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, circles, rectangles

I'm trying to construct a mathematical formula that will calculate a point `(x,y)` on a circle which contains a rectangle with a width `w` and height `h`, given another point on the circle `(a, b)` and the angle between them `α`. Has anyone encountered something like that before?

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: The angle $\alpha$ is the angle between what two things?

Comment: the angle  is the angle of rotation